# How to make session data part of assign in every live route?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to send session info about the user (or at least the user's token) to live view components. Is there a way I can add it in one place once instead of trying to do that in each of my mount/update of my live view pages?

I was thinking about the routes file perhaps?

Something like:

```
  scope "/", WebsiteWeb do
    pipe_through [:browser, :put_session_info_or_token_in_every_assign]
  

    live "/live", LiveLive
  end
```

or

```
  scope "/", WebsiteWeb do
    pipe_through :browser
  

    live "/live", LiveLive, :user_token : session.token
  end
```

The point why I want to do this is that session is not accessible from live view components, so when I want to access the user table from the component mount of update, I need to know the user's token which is stored in session. But I can't access the session from the update of mount of the live view component :(

And to do the same code calling in every of my live view pages seems a very bad and repetitive.

Do you know how to solve this problem of getting the token or the whole session info efficiently into the live view component?

Comment: 11 views in 4 days, WTF?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an [`on_mount` hook](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#on_mount/1), which can modify the socket before a LiveView's `mount/3` function is run.

```ex
defmodule WebsiteWeb.PutToken do
  import Phoenix.LiveView

  def on_mount(:default, _params, _session, socket) do
    {:cont, assign_new(socket, :user_token, fn -> get_token() end)}
  end
end
```

then attach it to a live session in your router

```ex
  live_session :default, on_mount: WebsiteWeb.PutToken do
    scope "/", WebsiteWeb do
      pipe_through :browser

      live "/", LiveLive
    end
  end
```